# Debian Wheezy update-grub: command not found

Tags: grub, debian

I'm trying to change my grub boot order, so I've changed `/etc/default/grub`, but I don't seem to have the `update-grub` command. I'm not sure if I'm using grub or grub2 because everything just says "grub".

How would I determine which version of grub I have installed?

Comment: Have you tried `grub-install -v`? See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107486/how-to-know-the-version-of-grub.

Comment: @HermanTorjussen I tried that, but grub-install was also not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `update-grub` script is here:

```
/usr/sbin/update-grub
```

When your system says `command not found` it can be that your user has not `/usr/sbin/` in its `$PATH` variable.

Anyway, the best way is to change to the root user with `su` and then run `update-grub` again.

To check which version of grub you have installed type this command:

```
root@host:~# dpkg --list | grep grub
ii  grub-common                         1.98+20100804-14+squeeze1    GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (common files)
ii  grub-pc                             1.98+20100804-14+squeeze1    GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS version)
```

Comment: Thank you. Running it as root worked great. I'll add /usr/sbin/ to my path, so I hopefully won't run into problems like this later.